# Convert &#XXXX; character from HTML to correct format

Tags: c#, html, utf-8, httpwebrequest

When I get HTML source page code in my c# app
I get some string like this :

```
&#1607;&#1605;&#1740;&#1606;&#1580;&#1608;&#1585;&#1740; &#1578;&#1587;&#1578;&#1740;
```

but in web page I see something like this :

> همینجوری
>   تستی

Now I want in my app when I get HTML source page code ,and when user want to see that , can see this string in correct format ,to wit user see this :

> همینجوری
>   تستی

in C# when I get string from WebRequest how can convert this string to correct format ?
kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`WebUtility.HtmlDecode()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354.aspx).